# Permission denied error running: sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, updates, root

This is the error that I get after executing `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y`

```
Hit:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:5 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease 
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Fetched 224 kB in 20s (11.0 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13:Permission denied) 
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286005/how-can-i-solve-be-aware-that-removing-the-lock-file-is-not-a-solution-and-may) (**Restart the computer**)

Comment: You forgot sudo after &&

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `sudo` in the second command so you did not have privileges to run the second command.  The `install` command also did not include the name of a package to install.

The correct syntax for the command you tried to run is:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y packagename
```

However this command is problematic for a few reasons:

- When you chain commands with `&&` you do not get to see if the first command was successful or if it needs attention before the second command is executed.
- When you use the `-y` option, you ignore confirmation prompts that would let you halt the process if something is not right.
- `sudo apt-get install` needs a target package.

It's almost always better to run the commands separately, without the `-y` option.  So one at a time, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Replace `packagename` with the name of the package you are trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because you aren't using correct syntax when writing the command. Assuming you are trying to install a package and update apt. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install <package>`. Also, you might want to try to add sudo in front of apt install to run it as root.