# error running the apt update

Tags: urban-terror

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Restart the computer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286005/how-can-i-solve-be-aware-that-removing-the-lock-file-is-not-a-solution-and-may)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/q/335794/)

Comment: Use the apt command with sudo.